# How to Run Background Tasks for Data Extraction PHP?

Tags: php, rabbitmq, shopify

I have this function that extracts information from Shopify and stores it in a database. However, it can take between 5 minutes to 5 hours, depending on the number of products the person has.

```
function shopifyProducts(){
try {
    global $ShopifyConnection, $shopifyBatchProcessData,$bdShopifyProcess;
    $sinceId = $bdShopifyProcess->getMaxIdShopify("Products") ?? 0;     
    do {
        set_time_limit(600);    
        $products = $ShopifyConnection->openActiveProducts($sinceId,5);
        foreach ($products as $product) {
            $shopifyBatchProcessData->batchProcess("Product",$product,"product");
            foreach ($product['variants'] as $variant) {
                $shopifyBatchProcessData->batchProcess("Variant",$variant,"product");
                $iventoryItem = $ShopifyConnection->getInventoryItem($variant['inventory_item_id']);
                $shopifyBatchProcessData->batchProcess("InventoryItem",$iventoryItem,"product");                
                $iventoryLevel = $ShopifyConnection->getInventoryLevel($variant['inventory_item_id']);                  
                $shopifyBatchProcessData->batchProcess("InventoryLevel",$iventoryLevel[0],"product");
            }
            $sinceId = $product['id'] + 1;
        }
        
        $productnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("products","product");
        $variantnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("variant","product");
        $inventoryitemnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("inventoryItem","product");
        $inventorylevelnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("inventoryLevel","product");
        $optionsnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("option","product");
        $optionsvaluenew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("optionValue","product");
        $imagesnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("image","product");
        $imagesvariantnew = $shopifyBatchProcessData->getParams("imageVariant","product");          
        
        $shopifyBatchProcessData->resetParams("product");
        $last_id=$sinceId-1;
        
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("Product", $productnew);   
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("Variant", $variantnew);   
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("Option", $optionsnew);    
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("OptionValue", $optionsvaluenew);  
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("Image", $imagesnew);  
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("ImageVariant", $imagesvariantnew);    
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("InventoryLevel", $inventorylevelnew); 
        $bdShopifyProcess->insertProcess("InventoryItem", $inventoryitemnew);   
        
    } while (!empty($products));            
        echo "<script>alert('Productos ingresados con éxito.'); window.location.href='../../home.php?option=configuracion';</script>";  
        exit();
            
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $last_id;
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    exit();
    //echo "<script>alert('Hubo un error al procesar productos.'); window.location.href='../../home.php?option=configuracion';</script>";
}
```

}

I've read that I can make it run in the background so the client doesn't have to keep the website open all the time. I've heard about RabbitMQ and Kafka, but I'm not sure if I can use them since I have the website hosted on SiteGround. I know they have cron jobs, but I need this to run when the client creates the account and not at a fixed interval.

Thank you very much!!